# Getting 404 error in Firefox & Chrome where as same thing running smoothly on IE what could be the reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

i need to make ma website browser independent it was specifically design for IE. now there are few button on clicking them i get 404 where as the same thing is running smoothly on IE.
i have used Ajax JSON jQuery in my Website

HTML CODE

```
<input type="hidden" selectedId="    <%=JspWriterHelper.escapeHtml(crt.getTempidPK())%>"  name="item<%=JspWriterHelper.escapeHtml(numItems)%>" value="false">
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
function createSelected()
{

var noOfSel = 0 ;
var returnValue ='' ;
var sand = 1;
var theForm = document.someForm;
for (var i = 0; i < theForm.length; i++)
{
    var e = theForm.elements[i];
    var s= theForm.elements[i].selectedId;

    if ((e.type == "hidden") && (e.value == "true") && (e.name.indexOf("item")==0) )
    {
        if(sand == 1)
        {
            sand = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            returnValue += '&';
        }
        console.log("the value of selected IDS="+e.selectedId);
        if (e.selectedId != undefined )
        {   
            returnValue += 'runTemplateId'+ noOfSelections +'='+ e.selectedId;
            noOfSelections ++ ;
        }
    }
}
return (returnValue+'&numberOfTemplates='+noOfSelections);
```

}

this is working fine for IE where e.selectedId is reflecting correct id but in Firefox this is UNDEFINED

can u tell me why the same thing is undefine for fire fox and crome ?

Comment: You need to show some example URLs that work in one browser, and don't work in the other.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing what code is being used to generate the query. The problem is most likely there. Can you show it?

Answer (score 0):

we can use  theForm.elements[i].getAttribute("selectedId") as this will work for firefox ,chrome and IE

where as theForm.elements[i].selectedId; will not work in firefox and chrome and it will give UNDEFINED as value. but the same thing will work fine in IE.